# Does TCP use an own thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

TCP sends ACKs when it receives a network packet. It also resends packets when a timeout occurs. Now my question is: In which Thread does TCP do this? Is there a secret TCP background thread that listens for received packets and timeouts and triggers the sending of ACKs and resends? Or does this only happen synchronously when I call, for example, `receive` on the socket? Or is there maybe an own TCP daemon process from the OS which handles this?

Although my question refers to `.net`, I think it applies generally to any TCP implementation in any language.

Comment: The answer to this question is to go find a good book or course on the topic - this is a huge question.  TCP is one layer in the network stack; it is managed by the operating system in a kernel mode driver (naturally, since the OS must sort packets and decide which application to route them to) and the operating system can use not just muliple threads, but often multiple processes to do all of this.

Comment: @J...: Well, your comment is already almost an answer :).

Comment: @gexicide I just understood what you meant by your question... Well, I agree with J... (:

Comment: @gexicide Yes, but it's not a very good one, and not one that will generally be useful except to satisfy an extremely shallow curiosity (which is not really on-topic).

Comment: TCP is handled inside the TCP/IP driver stack.  It runs at ring 0, it is thus a kernel thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP and sockets in general are not dependent on the language, but rather on the system, and it's architecture.

Addressing your questions:

**In which Thread does TCP do this?**
Definitely, not on any application thread. Usually, you can't really define that, since on kernel level there **may** be no such thing as "thread".

**Is there a secret TCP background thread that listens for received packets and timeouts and triggers the sending of ACKs and resends?**
If you consider OS a "secret background thread" then... yes.

**Or does this only happen synchronously when I call, for example, receive on the socket?**
When you call receive, the system checks whether there are any incoming packets in it's buffer. But then again, this may be more or less system-dependant.

**Or is there maybe an own TCP daemon process from the OS which handles this?** 
More or less this.

For more info you may want to check the following links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack
http://www.ece.virginia.edu/cheetah/documents/papers/TCPlinux.pdf

PS. I couldn't quickly find detailed information about Windows TCP/IP implementation, but since winsocks are kind of based on BSD sockets, I persume it's similar.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it magically happens and that you don't need to worry about it. But that's not want you want to know.

The OS does this. Incoming network packets cause an interrupt issues by the NIC. This interrupt is handled by drivers and passed eventually to the TCP component of the OS. The TCP component then does what's necessary to deliver the packet to the app. That could mean completing an outstanding IO request for data or queuing the data to be fetched later.

Answer (score 1):

In most modern common-purpose OSes, including Linux, other Unixes and Windows, this is done at the kernel land, not at the user land. At the kernel land, this can be done using different mechanisms, including kernel threads, but most often it is done with postponed timeout requests and short tasks executed by special thread pool for such executions.

For example, in a classical book "Design and implementation of 4.4BSD operating system" by McKusick & Co., which described the original BSD sockets implementation cloned by virtually all OS vendors, two timers are described for a TCP socket, "fast" and "slow" one. When a timer triggers, an action is scheduled at so-called "softinterrupt" level, outside of a particular process context. This version didn't attach such activity to a declared process, unlike modern versions. You should read this book (or its modern analog), or some of another classical series - R. Stevens' one on network programming. I don't know good analog for Windows with deep explanation of TCP/IP stack working.